# Finding the Taylor's series of $f(z)=e^{z}ln(1+z)$ about $z=0$ up to $z^{5}$ term

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

As the title shows, i would like to find the Taylor's series of $f(z)=e^{z}ln(1+z)$ about $z=0$ up to $z^{5}$ term.

What i tried to do was to find $f'(z), f''(z)$ and so on.
I computed $f'(z)=e^{z}(ln(z+1)+\dfrac{1}{z+1})$ and i realized that it is not viable to differentiate 5 times as there might be a better way of doing so to obtain the coefficients of this expansion.

How can i do this in a more efficient manner? Thanks in advance for any tips/help.

Comment: Multiplicate the Taylor's series of $e^z$ (around $z=0$) and $\ln(1+z)$ (around $z=0$). Then you will get all coefficients. $(\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty z^n a_n)\cdot (\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty z^n b_n)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty z^n \sum\limits_{k=0}^n a_k b_{n-k}$

Comment: Since $e^{x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}x^{n}$ and $ln(1+x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}x^{n}$, your suggestion yields $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^{n}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}(\frac{(-1)^{n-k+1}}{n-k})$. But this does not really resemble a taylor series , does it?

Comment: That's of course a Taylor series, please see the definition of Taylor series. And please: (1) Begin with $n=1$ for $\ln(1+x)$ (e.g. $b_0:=0$) or start with $\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}$ .  (2) Your double sum is  *incorrect*, look at the series which I've written! You have to be more concentrated to avoid mistakes.

Comment: Thank you for your tips. I will work it out again.